# URGENT: How to stop a page reloading too many times in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, redirection, cache, webpage

Having issues loading a page in Chrome.
I can get to a login page on https://login.scottishfalive.co.uk/Home/Index however once I input my details I get an error message, page isn't working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I have hunted through this forum but nothing has worked yet.

Actions I have tried are:
Clearing all my browser history, cookies and cache
Chearing cache and cookies relevant to the site
Checked my browser is up to date
Turned off all extensions one by one
Tried on different devices and browsers
Entered from a different IP
Cleared the host cache
Flushed socket pools
Tried incognito mode
Resetting password in an attempt to automatically be logged in

It's time sensitive as I have to register our team by next season and needs to be done by 30th of this month for next seasons insurance coverage. The system was updated on 14th June and I haven't been able to get anywhere by emailing them and others within the club, nobody knows what the issue is as other people can log into their account.

Comment: It's time sensitive as I have to register our team by next season and needs to be done by 30th of this month ,,,,,,    Make a bland, vanilla virtual machine and use this to register. That will work.

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry, it's not my site, I am just a registered user.

Comment: This is a server misconfiguration. Only fix possible is for the server administrator to undo whatever they did on 6/14.

Comment: I'll ask them again. As no other registered users are having the issue, they are puzzled themselves on how to resolve.

Comment: Did you complete the account migration: https://login.scottishfalive.co.uk/UserMigration